# Aligning columns in <select> with header in different font

Tags: javascript, html

I have a "table" created from a HTML `<select>` element. The table is divided into columns padded with `&nbsp` to make the columns line up. There is also a header, which also are padded to make them line up with the columns.

The problem is when using different fonts for the header and the "table" contents, like when the header is in Japanese and the table contents is in English. Because the Japanese font is wider, the header- and content-columns no longer match up. See attached image:

[image: Columns not lining up with header]

Is there a way to make the columns line up properly with the header?

As a further limitation, I can't just add or remove `&nbsp` as the language of the web-page is not static, but can be changed in session.

Edit: This is of course not the only page this kind of table is on. There are at *least* 15 of them.

Comment: you could check to find out what language is being used, then pad as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can only adjust your columns in the select options via `&nbsp;` you don't have that restriction in your header. You can position the columns in the header via CSS or use a table, like this:

```
<table style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="450"><tr>
<th align="left" width="26%">User</th>
<th align="left" width="51%">Name</th>
<th align="left">Bar</th>
</tr></table>
<select style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 12pt;">
<option>root&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Administrator&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;bar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, but since there are a few tables and they seldom have the same number of columns, how do I now what width to set on the column headers?

Comment: The character size in the options is fixed, so you can easily calculate the width of the header and its columns programatically. Since you know the size of your option columns in characters, and can find out the size of one character in the options columns on the screen, you can just multiply these numbers.

Comment: By the way, if you're using JavaScript, a table with clickable rows will be nicer and easier to build. Without JavaScript, you could add another column to the table with a radio or checkbox or submit button.